# Matrix Ring of semisimple algebra over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, semi-simple-rings

I'm working on the following question.

> Let $A$ be a finite dimensional semi-simple algebra over $\mathbb{C}$,
>   and set $M_n(A)$ ring of $n$ by $n$ matrices over $A$.
>
> (a) Show that $M_2(A)$ is semi-simple
>
> (b) If $\dim_\mathbb{C}(A)$ is prime, show that $M_2(A)$ is not simple
>
> (c) If $A$ is not commutative, there is a  $t\in M_2(A)$ with $t^3\neq 0$ and $t^4 = 0$

For part a) I think we use Artin-Wedderburn to get $A=\oplus M_{n_i}(D_i)$. So $M_2(A) = \oplus M_{2n_i}(D_i)$.  So $M_2(A)$ is semisimple

For part b) I don't see how prime is necessary.  It feels like anything greater than 1 should give $M_2(A)$ is not simple because we can decompose $A$ into a direct sum

For part c) Not sure how to do this, I'm thinking maybe we can use the decomposition found in part a somehow?

[Source: Spring 1992](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Pre_2012_papers/Algebra_Pre_2011.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

a) Yes, if you have Artin-Wedderburn, then what you wrote is a way to see a matrix ring of matrix rings is just a bigger matrix ring, and the same holds for finite products of them.

b) Consider $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, which has dimension $4$. $M_2(A)\cong M_4(\mathbb C)$ is simple. So... your feeling is not correct. In fact, $M_n(R)$ is simple iff $R$ is simple.

c) If $A$ is not commutative, then it contains somewhere a matrix ring which isn't trivial, and then $M_2(A)$ contains a matrix ring somewhere with side length at least $4$, when you expand the first matrix ring you found. So the task is to find a $4\times 4$ matrix with those properties, essentially.

Comment: For part b) is that enough to solve the question? If $M_2(A)$ was simple then A must also be simple $A$, which is not possible because it has dimension that is not a square? I think theres something off with my argument since we dont know the exact division ring over which A is a matrix ring. For part c) Why must A contain a matrix ring which isnt trivial if A is not commutative? Is it something to do with semisimplicity?

Comment: @iYOA I did not give you an answer to b, just a disproof of your conjecture. It does contain the kernel of a hint that you could develop though.  For c, if all the matrix rings were trivial, it would be a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb C$: you can see that with the artin wedderburn theorem.

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding Artin-Wedderburn.  Do we ever have information on what the specific division rings are in the direct product of matrix rings? In this case how do we know it's $\mathbb{C}$ rather than some other division ring? Is it enough to know that $A$ is a $\mathbb{C}$ algebra?

Comment: @iYOA The division rings must be finite dimensional extensions of $\mathbb C$, but since $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, there are no proper finite dimensional division ring extensions of $\mathbb C$. So the Artin Wedderburn theorem for semisimple $\mathbb C$ algebras says that they are all matrix rings over $\mathbb C$.